# "Runtime Exceptions in .NET Native Apps" when release application on UWP Windows10

Tags: c#, windows-10, win-universal-app

When I choose Debug mode, I run app correct and receive data but when I choose Release mode, I receive:

> "Runtime Exceptions in .NET Native Apps"

On UWP Windows10. I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: I've had some issues with interactive behaviors. Check if there are any and experiment with it.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to guess what can cause this problem. Try to install system like bugsense to catch exceptions from your application and get stacktrace. I knew that there was a bug in .Net Native compiler. Try to update Visual Studio and .Net Native compiler.